# Get current user in MS Project

Tags: sharepoint, ms-project, psi

How can I get current user guid in MS project?
This guid should be equals to guid from

```
ProjectDataSet.Project[i].PROJ_CHECKOUTBY
```

if I do a CheckOut.

I need to check: "is project checked out by me?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is class Resource (WebSvcResource)

```
Resource.GetCurrentUserUid();
```

This method returns user guid.